# Howto check if the first 4 characters of first name and first 4 characters of last name appear in the username

Tags: regex, grep, posix

I have a UNIX password file and I need to find, **using grep**, the entries where:

> the first 4 characters from first name and first 4 characters from the last name are inside the username.

This is my attempt:

```
grep -iE '^[^:]*([^:]{4})[^:]*([^:]{4})([^:]*:){4}(\1|\2)[^: ]* (\1|\2)'
```

And it does actually matches in some lines like these:

```
ldapsync:x:1118:65534:LDAP Synchronization,,,:/home/system/ldapsync:/bin/tcsh
johnkene:x:1943:1056:John Kennedy:/home/user/johnkene:/bin/tcsh
```

But it doesn't match in lines like these:

```
camad15:x:2674:1000:CAMAD2015 CAMAD2015:/home/user/camad15:/bin/sh
```

Comment: Here is a basic rule which you can use to decide if you need to use `grep` or `awk`: (1) search for a string or regular expression -> `grep` (2) search for a string or regular expression with an extra condition -> `awk`

Comment: I know but i'm trying to think of a way to do it with only grep, i think it should be possible.

Comment: If you want to do this only with grep, you should mention this in your post clearly and untag awk.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry i didn't notice that it was tagged, probably by mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The reason why it does not match on that line is that the username `camad15` has a length of 7 and your regular expression requires a minimum length of 8 to match.

Comment: Also, while the technique you implement is interesting, it will fail on a username like `XXXXYYY` and a full name as `XXXXaaaa XYYYbbbb` due to the overlap. Regular expressions cannot handle overlap.

Comment: The only possible solution with grep that might work is a double grep in a pipeline. The first grep searches the first 4 characters, the second grep the second. But now you need to ask yourself the question, What if my user is named `John Doe`, you only have 3 letters in the last name (also possible for the first name). So you should do something like `{1,4}` instead `{4}`. But this is again difficult because with backreferences you might have false positives again.

Comment: Yeah that's actually what i thought too right now, `grep -iE '^[^:]*([^:]{4})([^:]*:){4}\1' passwd | grep -iE '^[^:]*([^:]{4})([^:]*:){4}[^: ]* \1'`
The problem is to solve with first 4 characters of first name **and** first 4 characters of last name so i don't think i have to worry if a name is less than 4 characters.

Comment: it might be possible if you use the Perl extensions of grep, but then it is not posix.

Comment: @TetsuyaGR `grep ... | grep ...` is not solving the problem with only grep, it's solving it with shell+pipes+greps.

Answer (score 3):

This job suits more to `awk` than `grep` because of structure of each record delimited by a character.

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{
   split($5, a, / /)
   f4 = tolower(substr(a[1], 1, 4))
   l4 = tolower(substr(a[2], 1, 4))
}
index($1, f4) && index($1, l4)' /etc/passwd
```

```
ldapsync:x:1118:65534:LDAP Synchronization,,,:/home/system/ldapsync:/bin/tcsh
camad15:x:2674:1000:CAMAD2015 CAMAD2015:/home/user/camad15:/bin/sh
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me but i'm trying to do it with only grep because it's a homework assignment.

Comment: I do enjoy "we have to eat soup with a fork because it's homework" type questions. Obviously the best way to teach someone what a fork is for is to make them eat soup with it :-).